# DomContentLoaded time seems very long

Tags: html, performance

I am serving what is essentially a blank web page, just the `<html>`, `<body>`, and `<head>` tags with no javascript or css. The pages downloads in about 20 ms. Chrome is telling me it is taking the browser about another 80 ms until the DomContentLoaded event occurs. Is this normal? Seems like an awfully long time. Is there anything that can be done to speed this up?

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I just tried a blank html page on my local machine and the DomContnetLoaded time is just a few ms.

Answer (score 1):

Found out the problem. It was an Chrome Extension running in the background that runs a script on every page. Disable all extensions to fix.